# BC30188: Declaration expected ; New NetworkCredential VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

After years of doing a little programming on the side (Classic ASP for 12 years), I'm starting to do a lot more programming, and as a result am teaching myself .net.

I'm attempting to use UrbanAirship's API to send a test push notification through Apple's Push Notification Server (APNS). I found this sample code, but am having a hard time implementing it.

I'm receiving the error: BC30188: Declaration expected. Here is the code on this particular line:

```
req.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
```

Here is my entire code:

**pushvb.aspx**

`<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" src="pushvb_bg.aspx.vb" Inherits="UrbanAirship.uacode" %>`

`<%  Response.write(UrbanAirship.uacode.testing) %>`

**pushvb_bg.aspx.vb**

```
Imports System   
Imports System.Net  
Imports System.Text  
Imports System.IO  
Imports System.WinForms  

Namespace UrbanAirship  
public partial Class uacode  
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page  
    Public Const testing As String = "testing..."  
    Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/")  
    Dim postData As String = "{""aps"": {""badge"": ""+1"", ""alert"": ""pushvb"",""sound"": ""default"",""device_tokens"": ""token""}}"  
    req.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")  
    req.Method = "POST"  
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)  
    req.ContentType = "application/json"  
    req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length  
    Dim dataStream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()  
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)  
    dataStream.Close()  
    Dim resp As WebResponse = req.GetResponse() 
    dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream()  
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)  
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()  
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)  
    reader.Close()  
    dataStream.Close()  
    req.Close()  
end Class  
end Namespace
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much for taking the time to look over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... the answer is quite simple. Outside of Methods only declarations are allowed. You need to create a method in your Class which gets called from you, or is e.g. the Page Load Event.

Lines with dim and a new are accepted as a declaration, Public Const is also a Declaration.

The line `req.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")` is the first line in the code which is not a declaration, but an assignment, therfore it is shown in your Error Window.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I restructured the code and got it to work from there.